# Javascript: exclude from regex in replace

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

In this regex:

```
let str = "hello 〔world〕，foo、bar。";
str.replace(/(〔(.*?)〕|(、)|(，)|(。))/gi,'<div>$1</div>');
```

How to exclude these two square brackets "〔" and "〕" from the result ?

In order to get this result:

```
"hello <div>world</div><div>，</div>foo<div>、</div>bar<div>。</div>"
```

Comment: I would call the `replace` method 2 times. One for replacing the unwanted chars with _nothing_.

Comment: @undefined why not use the callback function of `replace` instead of calling it twice, i will go for `callback` function of `replace` as we can save extra work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a single group you can use two groups. and in callback based on group you can return the value accordingly

```js
let str = "hello 〔world〕，foo、bar。";
str = str.replace(/〔(.*?)〕|((…)|(。)|(，)|(、))/gi,(match,g1,g2)=>`<div>${g1 ? g1 : g2}</div>`);

console.log(str)
```